# downloadlistener not working

Tags: android

How is the DownloadListener supposed to work? Probably I miss something. I did the following:

- Register a DownloadListener at a WebView.
- Open a WebView with a HTML page, containing a link (works).
- If I click on the link, the DownloadListener is not called.

Here is a short portion of the code.

```
package rene.android.learnit;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.*;

public class ShowWeb extends Activity 
    implements DownloadListener
{
    public static Lesson L;

    WebView WV;

    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.showweb);

        WV=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.showweb);
        WV.setDownloadListener(this);
        WV.loadUrl("http://android.rene-grothmann.de/courses.html");

    }

    public void onDownloadStart (String url, String agent, String disposition,
            String mimetype, long size)
    {
        Main.log(url+" "+mimetype+" "+size);
    }
}
```

The logging works (I am using this everywhere to check my program), but nothing is logged, so the callback is not called. What happens is: The view tries to download the file, and fails, since zip files are not supported on my Android.

The link goes to a zip-file. It is a usual

```
<a href=...>...</a>
```

link.

I tried to figure out the alternative method of registering an intent for zip files. But the documentation is so sparse, I could not do that. If I have to, is there an example?

Any ideas?

Thanks, R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the DownloadListener is indeed not working. However, one can use the following trick:

```
package rene.android.learnit;

    import android.app.*;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.webkit.*;

    public class ShowWeb extends Activity 
    {
        public static Lesson L;

        WebView WV;

        @Override
        public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.showweb);

            WV=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.showweb);
            WV.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
            {
                public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) 
                {
                    Main.log(url);
                    if (url.endsWith(".zip"))
                    {
                        finish();
                    }
                    else super.onLoadResource(view,url);
                }           
            }
            );
            WV.loadUrl("http://android.rene-grothmann.de/courses.html");

        }
    }
```

This will allow to handle all zip files.

Answer (score 4):

The reason it doesn't work is that you have put the `onDownloadStart` method in the wrong place.

To be able to load links that you select on your first loaded page in your `WebView` you need to create a private class extending a `WebViewClient`. In this class you override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView v, String url)` otherwise the built-in browser will open the new URL instead.

This example explains that: http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html

Then, in your `onCreate()` method set `webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient())`. To be able to trigger on a download event let your `WebViewClient` (that you created from the example above) implement `DownloadListener` and override the `onDownloadStart` method.

Example:

```
private class WVClient extends WebViewClient implements DownloadListener {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView v, String u) {
        v.loadUrl(u);
        v.setDownloadListener(this);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Download: " + url);
        Log.i(TAG, "Length: " + contentLength);
    }
}
```

Comment: Then you need to create your own code that actually do something with the URL provided. I used Log.i() only for debugging purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that：

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {...
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try this, I 100% sure this will be work**

1. Create your own WebClient like this

```
public class WVClient extends WebViewClient implements DownloadListener {
    private static final String TAG = "WVClient";
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
        view.setDownloadListener(this);
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
        Log.d(TAG, "manageDownloadsAction: URL:" + url);
        Log.d(TAG, "manageDownloadsAction: UserAgent:" + userAgent);
        Log.d(TAG, "manageDownloadsAction: contentDisposition:" + contentDisposition);
        Log.d(TAG, "manageDownloadsAction: mimeType:" + mimetype);
        Log.d(TAG, "manageDownloadsAction: contentLength:" + contentLength);
    }
```

2. Then set your WebClient.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WVClient());
```

Comment: This is not working on Marsmalow

Answer (score -1):

after enable following option to WebSettings, things works smoothly.

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
```