# How i can enable to Download PDF via Webview

Tags: android, pdf, webview, download

i am very new to Android but i create a webview and it displays a wordpress page with a Download Link for a PDF in it, but when i tap on it nothing happends, i hope you can help me  :)

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.freizeitpark.plus"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.2" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".SplashActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
             android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:name="DroidWebViewActivity" >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Main Activity**

```
package com.freizeitpark.plus;

import com.freizeitpark.plus.info.Info;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;



public class DroidWebViewActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Context con;
    private WebView fweBview;
    private WebSettings webSettings;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    String url = Info.WebUrl;
    String url22 = Info.WebUrl22;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        con = this;
        try {
            if (!SharedPreferencesHelper.isOnline(con)) {
                AlertMessage.showMessage(con, "", "No internet connection");
                return;
            }
            updateWebView(url);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && fweBview.canGoBack()) {
            fweBview.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

    }

    private void updateWebView(String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar12);
        fweBview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.fbwebView);
        fweBview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        fweBview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        fweBview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        webSettings = fweBview.getSettings();

        webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        fweBview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        fweBview.loadUrl(url);

        fweBview.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());

    }

    // /---- Rating Button-----------------------------

    public void btnRating(View v) {

        try {

            alertbox(null, null);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

    }

    protected void alertbox(String title, String mymessage) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Dir gefällt die Freizeitparks Guide+ App? Dann würden wir uns über eine Bewertung sehr freuen :) ").setCancelable(
                false).setTitle("").setPositiveButton("Jetzt bewerten",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // finish the current activity
                        // AlertBoxAdvance.this.finish();
                        /*
                         * Intent myIntent = new Intent(
                         * Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
                         * startActivity(myIntent);
                         */
                        Intent viewIntent = new Intent(
                                "android.intent.action.VIEW",
                                Uri
                                        .parse(Info.GooglePlayAppUrl));
                        startActivity(viewIntent);
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Später",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // cancel the dialog box

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    // ------------ Share button---------------------

    public void btnShare(View v) {

        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                "    ");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Jetzt die Freizeitparks Guide+ App endlich im Play Store hier kannst du Sie dir kostenlos herunterladen https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.freizeitpark.plus");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Weiterempfehlen"));
    }

    // ------------ Home button---------------------
    public void btnHome(View v) {
        try {
            updateWebView(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        // Intent i = new Intent(DroidWebViewActivity.this,
        // DroidWebViewActivity.class); // your class
        // startActivity(i);

    }

    // ------------ Email button---------------------
    public void btnEmail(View v) {

        Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                new String[] { "" });
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, Info.eMailSubject);
        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Info.eMailDetails);
        email.setType("message/rfc822");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Per E-Mail :"));

    }

    // ------------ Call button---------------------
    public void btnPhone(View v) {
        try {
            updateWebView(url22);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        // Intent i = new Intent(DroidWebViewActivity.this,
        // DroidWebViewActivity.class); // your class
        // startActivity(i);

    }


    }
```

HOPE YOU CAN HELP ME SO MUCH! :)

Answer (score 6):

Try to add this to to your code: (probably in your `updateWebView` method) This will intercept any downloads and send them to the standard android download manager.

```
 mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
            String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
            long contentLength) {
                Request request = new Request( Uri.parse(url));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "myPDFfile.pdf"); 
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);        
   }
});
```

Note that this will use the same filename everytime, so your file may get replaced unless you modify the code to use a different filename.

Comment: don't work i copy that to my main activity but i just get errors and the app crash x.x i am very new to android but i dont get it to work :(

Comment: I bet the reason is because `setDestinationInExternalPublicDir` is called and there's no `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission requested: `java.lang.SecurityException: need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to use DESTINATION_FILE_URI: uid 10406 does not have android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.`

Comment: From fragment, constant should be referenced as `Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE`

Comment: "setDownloadListener **sets the listener when the WebView *doesn't think the content can be handled*** by the rendering engine", from/thanks to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5798702/2162226

Answer (score 0):

JonasCz's answer updated for **kotlin** users, requesting storage permissions previously.

```
    webview.setDownloadListener { url, _, _, _, _ ->
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context!!, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity!!, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), REQUEST_CODE)
        } else {
            val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url))
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "myPDFfile.pdf")
            val dm = context?.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager?
            dm!!.enqueue(request)
        }
    }
```