# Webview Download listener never calls

Tags: android, webview, download-manager

Download listener never calls and I am also not getting dynamic download link.

I have one website that contain **Download** button, while clicking on button it generates download link for document, while I click on download button it will successfully downloads documents via **chrome browser** directly but using web view it is not automatically downloads documents as well not getting any call of listener.

```
webView.loadUrl(WEBSITELINK);

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            Log.v("Url:","shouldOverrideUrlLoading");
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            // download link generates dynamically by clicking on button

            webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('download').click();})()");

        }



webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {

            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

            request.setMimeType(mimeType);
            //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
            //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
            request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: refert this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65684942/8258305

Answer (score 0):

setDownloadListener sets the listener when the WebView doesn't think the content can be handled by the rendering engine

for more information follow this link [setDownloadListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797976/downloadlistener-ondownloadstart-never-called)

or this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926629/downloadlistener-not-working)

Comment: Is there any way to force fully call listener?

Answer (score 0):

Inside oncreate method write this code

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("place your link here");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse(url));

            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!

            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", //To notify the Client that the file is being downloaded
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that：

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {...
```